# ActiveMQ message groups equivalent in Spring TaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring

Is there any equivalent of [ActiveMQ message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) for the [Spring TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) abstraction? The idea being, that when consuming messages from a message queue (an ActiveMQ that utilizes message groups), then the execution of message processing tasks would be performed in-order (a task processing a message from a message group does not start before the previous task processing a message from that group has not finished).

An option is to ditch the TaskExecutor (in my case, a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) and use a fixed amount of worker threads, each of which consumes directly from the MQ, however that loses the execution flexibility provided by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, therefore I'm hesitant to do that.

At first glance, there appears to be no such functionality in Spring, however I refuse to believe that I'm the first who has stumbled upon this kind of issue and that this has not been solved before. Any insights welcome :)

Comment: Spring integration has an [Aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/aggregator.html) which aggregates correlated messages. Not quite the same as tasks, I know.

Comment: I don't actually require aggregation, just ordering...of sorts.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - no there isn't. A TaskExecutor is just an abstraction of thread pool so doesn't have any knowledge of routing between the threads. Depending on exactly how you want to control things, have you looked at writing a simple route in [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) to control the routing of messages to your threads?

Comment: At first glance, the Camel option seems at least as "hardwired" as my current "solution"...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know anything similar to that of **ActiveMq** that can be used with **Spring TaskExecutor** .

***Your Requirement***

> " The idea being, that when consuming messages from a message queue (an
>   ActiveMQ that utilizes message groups), then the execution of message
>   processing tasks would be performed in-order (a task processing a
>   message from a message group does not start before the previous task
>   processing a message from that group has not finished). "

***My suggestion :***

> *The requirement you have specified, can be executed without having any trouble in simple Java .*

You can create a virtual Queue using a simple table in the database and use custom query to generate the content in the way you need.

When the data's are there in the database you can do all the operations like fetching the similar data, reusing the data etc. Once you implement these simple steps all the operations that you do with ActiveMQ can be accomplished without much overhead.

1. Insert each request into the database.
2. Fetch the data according to the requirements.
3. Build the content you need from the data's you have fetched.
4. Do the operations you need to do using the task Scheduler.
5. Remove the Data from the database.

I don't see anything much troubling in your requirements to use some custom codes.

Hope it helps. Good Luck :)

***Solution Without using a Database.***

1 Create a Class file with all the elements you need. Like id, name, Address etc.

2 Create a static final `HashMap` like this with key as the grouping value and an `arraylist` of `className` as the value.

```
public static final HashMap<Key, List<ClassName>> map= new HashMap<Key, List<ClassName>>();
```

3 Now add the class to the list in the `HashMap` if there exist an entry for the key. else put a new hash value with the new key and an `ArrayList` with the class.

```
if(map.containsKey(className.getId())){
            map.get(className.getId()).add(className);
        }
        else{
            List<ClassName> lstClass= new ArrayList<ClassName>();
            lstClass.add(className);
            map.put(className.getId(), lstClass);
        }
```

4 Now for each key you will be getting an `ArrayList` of the class `ClassName` which contains all the class with the key

This will work just like the DB. You wont be able to condition based on multiple values in this example. But anything is possible with alterations based on your requirement.

Comment: Another database dependency is something I'm afraid I cannot afford.

Comment: same thing can be implemented using static hashMap will be easy and does not require another table.!!

Comment: Implementing this myself with all the possible pitfalls is the thing I'm trying to avoid all along. I kind of hoped that something like that would have been done already.

Comment: @Manjabes This is definitely a solution, but i not familiar with any packages that do this requirement.!!